# transform.rotatin.z возвращает странный угол

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 mousePosition;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public GameObject bulletSpawn;

    private float headRotation;
    public static float rotation_z;

    private void Start()
    {
        headRotation = transform.localRotation.z; // при transform.rotation.z возвращает тот же угол
        Debug.Log("Z rotaton: " + transform.rotation.z);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // поворот пушки
        var difference = mousePosition - transform.position;
        var angle = 90;
        difference.Normalize();
        // вычисление угла
        rotation_z = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        // поворачиваем
       float additionalAngle = 0;
       if (headRotation == 90)
            additionalAngle = 0;
        else if (headRotation == -90)
            additionalAngle = 180;
        else if (headRotation == 0)
            additionalAngle = -90;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation_z + additionalAngle);
```

Мои спрайты имеют разный угол, однако выполняют оду и туже роль. Атлас довольно большой и поэтому я решил написать пару if для решения проблемы с разными углами. Однако, когда я взял данные об угле, ожидая увидеть угол z из инспектора, обнаружил угол 0,7071068, вместо 90 (и -0,7071068 при -90). Что произошло? Где он взял этот угол?

Comment: Даже если так: почему в методе Start() он выводит этот угол в консоли? Да и 90 градусов = 1,5708 радиан, а не 0,7071068.

Comment: в методе Start вы выводите значение transform.rotation, которое представлено в виде кватерниона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы понять, как работают повороты объектов в Unity (да и не только в Unity), придется окунуться в пространственную геометрию.

Что такое поворот? Это изменение положение объекта относительно некой оси.

Как можно описать поворот? Двумя способами:

1. Используя [углы Эйлера](https://blog2k.ru/archives/1119) - рысканье, тангаж и крен. По ссылке - краткий экскурс для начала.
2. Используя [кватернионы](https://blog2k.ru/archives/1124) - аналогично.

Кватернион кодируется 4-мя числами - `{x, y, z, w}`, где `{x, y, z}` - вектор оси поворота, а `w` - угол поворота.

Принципиальная разница в том, что углами Эйлера мы поворачиваем систему координат, а с помощью кватернионов задаем вектор оси и доворачиваем на нужный угол.

Советую вам потратить время и разобраться с математикой, потом будет гораздо проще (проверено на личном примере).